# Can't find SystemProperty.CellularSystemConnectedGprs in WindowsMobile.Status

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm taking over someone's code and I'm having an issue where I can't find the following three properties which should be part of Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status according to everything I've seen.

```
SystemProperty.CellularSystemConnectedGprs
SystemProperty.CellularSystemConnectedHsdpa
SystemProperty.CellularSystemConnectedEdge
```

is there a different version of this dll that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. When I installed the Mobile 6.5 DTK it installed the version 5 SDK for some arb reason.

I upgraded the mobile SDK to 6.5 and now it's working